# how to fix invalid url or port error in Android?

Tags: android

```
String str1="http://10.0.2.2/moodle";   
String str4="admin";
String str5="S12345s@";

try{
    String getToken = str1 + "/login/token.php?username=" + str4 + "&password=" + str5 + "&service=moodle_mobile_app";
    String inputLine = null; 
    URL url = new URL(getToken.toString()); 
    System.out.println("Port----------->"+url.getPort());
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())); 
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { 
        System.out.println("test1"+inputLine); 
    } 
    in.close(); 
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
}
```

when i try to get the token from localhost moodle course web and i got port number as -1.
I got this error":"Invalid url or port. for above code
please help me to fix this error.

Comment: Why are you calling toString on getToken? That's already a string...

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same problem. To resolve it I had to edit the following line inside the `config.php` file located in the Moodle root folder (`/var/www/moodle/config.php` in my case, on Ubuntu 12.10):

```
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://10.0.2.2/moodle';
```

You'll have to use the IP address which your device will see as the host of the Moodle web server (in case of the emulator, the host machine is seen at 10.0.2.2).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [URI constructors](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html) and use those instead. Building by hand is a bad way to do it.